# Adding leading zero in Excel custom formats?

Tags: excel, formatting

I need to format some financial data (in German unfortunately - so codes are a bit different!), so that its shown in thousands.

So far I am using:

```
€ ##.###,0.
```

this converts numbers as such:

> 232,29    into    € ,2
>
> 1.085,17  into    € 1,1
>
> 2.849.817,95      into    € 2.849,8

which in general is correct. However, how can I get the 232,29 to show as € 0,2 and not just € ,2

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In excel formatting, '#' means optional digit and '0' means mandatory digit, '0' if non exists.

That means you should probably use:

`€ ##.##0,0.`

Comment: thanks! Works great, except need to keep the last dot, so it equals: `€ ##.##0,0.`                thanks again!